# I can not Navigating Between Different Navigators in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have done 3 routes files:

1. app.routes.js (having the routes that the LOGGED user can access)

```html
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard';

const AppStack = createStackNavigator();

const AppRoutes = () => (
    <AppStack.Navigator>
        <AppStack.Screen
            name='Dashboard'
            component={Dashboard}
        />
    </AppStack.Navigator>
);

export default AppRoutes;
```

2. auth.routes.js (Having the SignIn screen on this route for users not logged)

```html
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import SignInView from '../pages/SignIn';
import Loading from '../pages/Loading';

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
const AuthRoutes = () => (
    <AuthStack.Navigator>
        <AuthStack.Screen
            name='SignIn'
            component={SignInView}
        />
        <AuthStack.Screen
            name='Loading'
            component={Loading}
        />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
);

export default AuthRoutes;
```

3. routes.js ( This route verify if user are logged or not, and redirection to the correct Stack)

```html
import React from 'react';

import AppRoutes from './app.routes';
import AuthRoutes from './auth.routes';
import { Logado } from '../services/apiUser';

const Routes = () => {
    //aqui vai o if com o retorno se esta ou nao logado se nao authroutes se sim approutes
    if(Logado){
        return <AppRoutes />;
    }else{
        return <AuthRoutes />;
    }
};

export default Routes;
```

Now i am trying to call Dahsboard screen on the AppStack in app.routes.js file, like this:

```html
import {ButtonDashboard,Container,ButtonTitle,TextInformation,} from './styles';

const Dashboard = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <ButtonDashboard onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AuthStack', {screen:    'Dashboard' })}>
        <ButtonTitle>Call Dashboard screen</ButtonTitle>
      </ButtonDashboard>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

I followed the Docs and still receiving this error:

console.error: The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"neme":"AuthStack", "params": {screen":"Dashboard"}} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'AuthStack'?

If you are trying to navigate to a screen  in a nested navigator, see (react navigation site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your AuthStack

```
 <AuthStack.Navigator>
        <AuthStack.Screen
            name='SignIn'
            component={SignInView}
        />
        <AuthStack.Screen
            name='Loading'
            component={Loading}
        />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
```

in here we don’t have any Screen named "Dashboard" ! so the valid value for screen can be **Signin** and **Loading**. so when you want to navigate to any screen avoid using screen props or pass a valid screen name which is defined! and also not the stack but the Component you made with that stack which named **AuthRoutes**

Comment: sorry bout that this just was a desperate attempt to do it, but i've tryied like you said.
navigation.navigate('AppRoutes', {screen: 'Dashboard' }) still does not work
but thaks for the very quick ansewer

Comment: just use navigation.navigate('AppRoutes') if you still got the problem share your codes i will help you

Comment: Hi, thaks for the answer i have had not tryied this before, but i got the error
"navigate with payload {"name":AppRoutes"} was not hendled by any navigator"

Comment: i want to edit your codes because i dont have time to check and i will be able to edit it

Comment: https://github.com/cirulei/src
i upload on github to  you, thanks very much, i followed to many times the docs ant yet i couldn't get it done;

Comment: on "routes" are my 3 routes files, and on pages are my Dashboard and SignIn, any doubt i'm here to clarify

Comment: the repo is empty

Comment: sorry bout that, i'm still learning things
https://github.com/cirulei/vitrine
try this one

Comment: im chking nowww

Comment: can you send the whole project? ios android file package.json and ,,,

Comment: cos it takes time to make it from scratch

Comment: sure i can, im still trying and still getting the error

Comment: Sorry bout that, you can try it now https://github.com/cirulei/vitrine

Comment: Thank you very much for the time u are spending with this, i appreciated

Comment: i am clonining it

Comment: good morning, i've tryied some others ways and steel nothing :/

Comment: did you take a look?

Comment: you are my last hope

Comment: can you delete only node_module,pods folder in ios and build folder on android and then zip and send it?
use Weshare and get a link from there and share it. i will help

Comment: i am doing it, but i think here the server do not work well its saying "8 hours remain", why can't i just delete my Build folder in android and push to git again and you just clone it?

Comment: your code on github needs maintenance to run, and i am out of time , that is the reason

Comment: do you use telegram?

Comment: yes,but its now on 20 % on Weshare, what you preffer

Comment: @CorleoneSr  text me on telegram

Comment: now its korking, i already sent you a message there